# i have faced an error in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

i am developing a site in WordPress and, i am using **PHP version 5.6** and i have faced this error:

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/c118209438/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1578

i want to hide this error , for that i used these lines but it does not give me appropriate output ...

```
error_reporting(0)
error_reporting(E_ALL &~ E_DEPRECATED);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED
```

thanks for advance ...

Comment: Why do you want to hide that stop using very old `mysql` and switch the plugin to `mysqli` or `PDO` then that error will go away. Also in new versions of `PHP` they have completely removed `mysql` support. IF can't redo the plugin then find a new updated one.

Comment: is it possible for time being to hide this error?

Comment: In fact thats only a deprecation warning not an error. Using mysql_connect is deprecated, just use mysqli (http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php) or PDO (http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: i have changed the mysql_connect to mysqli_connect on wp-includes/wp-db.php file on line 1578 but warning still here ...